# How to configure Application Insight with Window Service

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have configured Application Insight with window service in `.net` but I'm unable to post telemetry data in insight while I have also added instrument key. Can anyone suggest on that.

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
// Alternative to setting ikey in config file:
tc.InstrumentationKey = "8fccf8e5-0ef5-47f9-9f8b-5fc1f92a8f36";// "4637b838-11f4-41c0-a67e-ef03676c7339";
tc.TrackRequest("testRequest", DateTime.Now.Date,ts, "100", true);
// Set session data:
tc.Context.User.Id = "Pradeep";
tc.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
tc.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
tc.TrackTrace("Trace-Test", SeverityLevel.Information);
// Log a page view:
tc.TrackPageView("Form3");
```

Comment: when you run in debug mode from visual studio, what you see? any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instrumenting windows service with Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704977/instrumenting-windows-service-with-application-insights)

Comment: Add `tc.Flush()` at the end, right after `tc.TrackPageView("Form3");
`. Does it help? Bear in mind it takes a while for data to be visible in the portal.