# Application insights without changing the source code

Tags: azure

When I have configured application insights by installing the packages to the solution, its working fine and able to capture telemetry data.

Now, I want to integrate application insights with my windows services (running on premises vms) without installing the nuget packages (Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer) or inserting the instrumentation key to the source code. Is it possible?

I have tried to copy all the required dlls (application insights related) to the output directory of my service and used Application Insights configuration to set the instrumentation key but its not sending any telemetry data.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to do this? This might lead to a better solution for your overall problem.

Comment: There is no magical process that goes through the assemblies you put there and guessed that, by adding the instrumentation key, you want to enable application insights. You need some configuration. What is it you want to track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate your Windows services (on-premises) to send telemetry to App insights, but without installing the NuGet packages and providing Instrumentation key is not possible. There are some other processes to follow too for your use-case.

Refer [this official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop),

> Applications hosted on premises, in Azure, and in other clouds can all
>   take advantage of Application Insights. The only limitation is the
>   need to [allow communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses) to the Application Insights service. For
>   monitoring Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications, we recommend
>   [Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-mobile-center-quickstart).

[Refer this SO thread for better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704977/instrumenting-windows-service-with-application-insights)